# Access reactjs props and states from js

Tags: reactjs, minify

I am modifying a minified webapp and it uses reactjs and I am making plugin that will add elements conditionally base on Reactjs props and states. But I do not know how to get reactjs props and states from dom elements because source code is minified. I have jquery and javascript es6 and running on electron (chromium).

Comment: This just seems like its asking for a world of hurt... Do you have access to the source? I just don't know how nicely a react app with respond to its state/props being manipulated outside of the react ecosystem

Comment: not manipulated i want to read them

Comment: The React Dev Toolbar does this already. You should read the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) to get some insights on how to do that. Ideally, I'd make a JS wrapper around my react component to make it pluggable with non-react JS code. Also, there are perfectly valid scenarios, mostly where you are making an embeddable widget, e.g. tweet or survey where this is needed. E.g. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/web-components.html.